# How to open PDF file on TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, tableview

In my app users can save web pages as PDF files on a TableView. Now how to open PDF file after clicking on a cell? The following codes is just I started with if let. You can advise your way to do it if it is different. Thanks.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let pdfToOpen = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("pdfSaved") as? NSData {

}
```

Comment: I suggest creating a UIWebView for this

Comment: Thanks. I know if I save url of the web page on a TabView and I can open it after clicking on the cell.  But I don't know the codes to open a PDF file. Can you advise?

Comment: Look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682245/how-to-load-local-pdf-in-uiwebview-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use webview to show pdf data like,

```
 [webview loadData:PdfContent MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

pass your data which you get from `nsuserdefault` in place of pdfContent.

it's objective c code convert this line in swift.

In swift something like,

```
func loadData(_ data: NSData,
    MIMEType MIMEType: String,
   textEncodingName textEncodingName: String,
     baseURL baseURL: NSURL)
```

if you want to open from `url` then,

```
let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf")
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is what I need and am working on swift code now. Can you advise how to put MIMEType: String ? What string should be used here?

Comment: I think "application/pdf" you should use