# Swift 3.0 - Getting a strange log message when loading the PDF in Webview

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I am loading PDF file by using webview with the code written in swift 3.0 in my app. I used the following code,

> let req = NSURLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL))
>
> webView.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)

Note: fileURL is the local path of the PDF file

I am debugging in the iPhone(iOS version 10.1.1). I am getting the following log message when loading the PDF in the webview,

> objc[289]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x17045d160 overreleased
>   while already deallocating; break on
>   objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
>
> objc[289]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x17045d4c0 overreleased
>   while already deallocating; break on
>   objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
>
> objc[289]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x17045d4f0 overreleased
>   while already deallocating; break on
>   objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
>
> objc[289]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x17045d8e0 overreleased
>   while already deallocating; break on
>   objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
>
> objc[289]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x17045dcd0 overreleased
>   while already deallocating; break on
>   objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug

Note: I don't get the above log message when debugging in the iPhone(iOS version 10.2)

I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: why you not tried with **UIDocumentationInteractioncontroller** for load PDF

Comment: see this http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2016/09/how-to-create-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-in-swift-language-ios-sdk.html

Comment: Hi. I used to load the PDF in my app scope itself. By using UidocumentationInteraction controller, it will be redirecting to the iBook app or some other related app for loading the PDF. So that my only one option is go for webview.

Comment: no it will be open inside the app in seperate VC

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682245/how-to-load-local-pdf-in-uiwebview-in-swift

Comment: Whether we can open the PDF in seperate VC by using UidocumentationInteraction controller?