# Video thumbnail image moving for inset image using jwplayer video embedded Html content in web view from navigate in swift

Tags: html, ios, css, swift

[image]I am using html content for uiwebview in swift but going to one view controller to another controller navigate suddenly moving inner video image.i tried to clear web view- refer link [How To Clear A UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576154/how-to-clear-a-uiwebview) and
also used autoresizing autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth but didn't solved.Clear web view cache using in viewDiddisappear cann't get solution[

**Swift 3.0 code:**

```
let htmlString:String = descriptionHtml

 webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)

 webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

 webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

let aStr = String(format: "%@%x", "document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ", webView.frame.size.width)

 webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: aStr) 

 webView.delegate = self
```

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Example Html content :<div style=\"position:relative; padding-bottom:56.25%; overflow:hidden;\"><iframe src=\"http://content.jwplatform.com/players/dtBfxQaG-zyPe2GHK.html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"auto\" allowfullscreen=\"\" style=\"position:absolute;\"></iframe></div>